# issue interpreting internet connection speed

Tags: performance

I had someone telling me that they offer internet speed like:

"The price quoted below is based on download/upload speed range.

10MB-20MB --- 1 or 2 days $xx1
20MB-40MB---- 1 or 2 days $xx2
40MB-60MB---- 1 or 2 days $xx3"

It does not make sense to me because internet speed is measured in Mbps not in MB and download speed is usually higher than upload.
The person is an IT and it is very strange to me that she refers to internet speed like that.

Is there another way to read options she suggested and I do not see that?

Thanks, T

p.s. "they" is a provider of short-term WiFi or wired connection.

Comment: We're missing a lot of information. What's the "they"? Is this a hosting provider? A provider of short-term WiFi? An ISP?

Comment: A provider of short-term WiFi thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably meant (for eg "10MB-20MB --- 1 or 2 days $xx1")

 1: varying between 10-20 MBps (80-160Mbps) 
2: between 10-20Mbps (if incorrectly capitalised)
3: they could mean 10-20 MB download limit and not be referring to speed at all.

In all cases they mean you can have that speed/capacity for 1 or 2 days. 

 they are probably just referring to the download speed, or both the upload and download speed are in the same range (probably upload speed towards the bottom of the range, download towards the top).

you will probably need to ask them to be more specific, since there are multiple ways it could be interpreted.